# x509FindType="FindBySerialNumber" Fails but Find Certificate… finds it

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a wfc app developed in VS 2010/C# which has been running flawlessly for 6 months. The cert is expiring so we created a new one. I use `<*clientCertificate findValue="xx xx xx xx xx xx" x509FindType="FindBySerialNumber"/>`
 in the `app.config` file to find the cert. This has always worked.

The new cert has a new serial number, so I changed the code to match and it can’t find the cert. I manually typed the serial number in because I know you can sometimes get odd characters when you copy from the cert store and paste in the VS.

To verify that I have the correct number, I then copy the serial number out VS and paste it in to the “Find Certificate…” dialog box in the cert store and it finds it.

I have tried `FindByName`, `FindbyThumbPrint`, `FindBySerial` number and all fail.

Has anyone experienced this before?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was choosing the store to import the cert to. When I let the wizard choose the store it put it in a different place that the original cert which was about to expire. I have no idea why, but that solved *this* problem. Dealing with certs can be such a pain in the ass.

Greg

Comment: One other point to be careful of-- when copying a certificate ID out of the Windows Certificate viewer, you often end up copying an invisible character that breaks lookups. (Use ClipSpy to see this effect)